# Has anyone integrated Okta with GitLab successfully?

Tags: single-sign-on, gitlab, okta, okta-api

We would like to integrate Gitlab with Okta, any advice on how to get started?

Comment: I would start by reading the [GitLab Documentation on adding SAML support](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/saml.html) and using that in concert with the [Okta guide for setting up a SAML application](http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/setting_up_a_saml_application_in_okta.html). If that doesn't work then I suggesting emailing developers@okta.com for more detailed support.

Comment: This is now supported (for Premium+) with [self-managed GitLab 15.8+ instances as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964630/6309).

Answer (score 2):

I met this question a few times while trying to get this working, posted the results on the following GitLab issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14122#note_17669455

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#okta-scim-integration-application-for-gitlabcom), but only for Premium and more (so not free), and only for gitlab.com (not self-managed)

> ### Okta SCIM Integration Application for GitLab.com
>
> We now offer an Okta SCIM integration application for Gitlab.com groups!
>
> When Okta SCIM is provisioned for a GitLab group, membership of that group is synchronized between GitLab and Okta. This reduces group administrator time spent to onboard and offboard users.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/saml_sso/scim_setup.html#okta-configuration-steps) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/1774).

---

Update 2023: [GitLab 15.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/01/22/gitlab-15-8-released/#scim-support-for-self-managed-gitlab) (January 2023) add support for self-managed GitLab instances as well! (still premium+ only).

> ### SCIM support for self-managed GitLab
>
> Self-managed GitLab now supports the open standard **System for Cross-domain Identity Management** (**SCIM**), which allows you to automatically:
>
> - Create users.
> - Remove users by deactivating their SCIM identities.
>
> Previously, this was only available for GitLab.com.
>
> SCIM enables GitLab administrators to completely automate their user lifecycle management.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_8/manage-scim-token.png -- SCIM support for self-managed GitLab]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/scim_setup.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8902).

---

Plus, [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#improved-onboarding-experience-for-samlscim-provisioned-users) (March 2023) adds:

> ### Improved onboarding experience for SAML/SCIM provisioned users
>
> When users are provisioned with SAML or SCIM, the link in their email confirmation now directs them to sign in through their identity provider.
>
> Previously, users were directed to the GitLab sign-in page, which was potentially confusing.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_10/manage_email_login.jpg -- Improved onboarding experience for SAML/SCIM provisioned users]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/saml.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/298753).